# SSRS mapping of zip codes to state map

Tags: reporting-services, maps

I have a dataset with city names, zipcode, lat and long among other data. I want to show the number of contacts by city or zipcode. The state maps that come with SSRS only have county level available. Yeah, I can show how many contacts took place on a county level, but I need it by city or zipcode. Any way to do this with the state maps that come with SSRS?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your latitude and longitude to a geographic point in SQL. Then SSRS will let you add markers at points on the map. You can still use labels etc. The SQL function would look something like this:

```
geography::Parse('POINT(' + CAST([Longitude] AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + 
                CAST([Latitude] AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')')
```

Here's a reference: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/convert-latitude-longitude-to-geography-point.aspx

**EDIT:**

1. Use the "New layer wizard" to add a layer to your state map.
2. Select the "SQL Server spatial query" option.
3. Specify the geographic point from your dataset.

This will add all the points as a layer over your map.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I still don't know what to do. I had already gotten the geo point column but don't know how to get it to display on a state map. I seem to get different results every try:). The latest shows me the entire earth with what might be my data crammed into a tiny spot. <br/> >>Then SSRS will let you add markers at points on the map.<br/> I can add a point but can't see how to link that point with my data.

Comment: Thanks man, works for me . except the map of Australia does not show